# Adding node items to Java Graph with for loop

Tags: java, graph, edges

I'm trying to add newly created objects to a grid and to a graph. Specifically, how to efficiently add nodes to a graph with a for loop. They grid has been set up as a double array, in order to update the initial view. (The object grid is the model and updates the view via push). I also set up a HashMap using the items in i and j within the for loops in order to define the object's keys. However, in order to set up a graph in order to later calculate the shortest path from node to node, I need to add these nodes to a Graph. I would like to use Djikstra's algorithm to calculate the shortest path. I could create a conditional statement to define what are corner nodes and edge nodes in the grid and define what items would have bi directional edges but this seems to be a 'long cut'. Is there any way to add nodes to a graph with a pre determined matrix size, such as for example 20 X 20, similar to a double array?

Below is the constructor code on how I am creating the first two items (creating double array and HashMap):

```
// **Constructor
// Construct a new Grid object. Sets up a HashMap of square object in order efficiently to get 
// and add Square objects later.
public ObjectGrid(Integer width, Integer height) 
{
    // View
    gui = new GUI();        // Instantiate GUI
    boardView = new BoardView(width,height);        // Instantiate BoardView

    // Initialize Gui, set time and add simulation event listener to model (ObjectGrid)
    gui.initGUI(BoardView);
    gui.addSimulationEventListener(this);

    // Initialize turnInSteps variable count to 0
    turnInSteps = 0;

    // Initialize numberOfDays variable count to 0
    numberOfDays = 1;

    // Instantiate HashMap
    objectHashMap = new HashMap();

    // Declare new object grid using double array of type objects.
    // Size determined by parameter Integer values in constructor
    myObjectGrid = new ObjectType[width][height];

    // Instantiate Graph object
    Graph graph = new ListGraph();

    // For loop sets up the initial grid with ObejctType using a double array. After
    // the completion of this loop, the grid will have XXX objects in the grid
    // each with a reference to an object. Objects are also added 
    // to HashMap using coordinates as keys and square objects as values.
    for(int i = 0; i < width; i++) 
    {  
        // Iterate through rows
        for(int j = 0; j < height; j++) 
        {  
            // Iterate through columns
            myObjectGrid[i][j] = new ObjectType();  // Instantiate a new Square at each row/column using default constructor
            gridView.addObjectView(myObjectGrid[i][j].getObjectView(), i, j);  // Add object view to each row/column placement
            String hashMapKey = (i + ", " + j); // Use values from i and j as Key for objects HashMap
            myObjectGrid[i][j].setID(hashMapKey);  // Add ID's for each ObjectView to display in object using values from i and j
            objectHashMap.add(hashMapKey, myObjectGrid[i][j]);  // Add object to HashMap using string value of coordinates as key
            listGraph.add(myObjectGrid[i][j]);

            // Pseudo code
            if (i != (width-height) && (j != height) etc) 
            {
                listGraph.addBidirectionalEdge(mySquareGrid[i][j], (mySquareGrid[i][j+1]), 1);
                listGraph.addBidirectionalEdge(mySquareGrid[i][j], (mySquareGrid[i+1][j]), 1);
                listGraph.addBidirectionalEdge(mySquareGrid[i][j], (mySquareGrid[i+1][j+1]), 1);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: and what is your question?

Comment: apologies for not being specific. (first post on this site). The question is how to add objects as nodes to a graph, using a for loop. If a for loop isn't the proper way, guidance to another method would be of help. With the unit tests that I did the vertices in the graph return null.

Comment: It's better to update your post with this question.

Comment: Hi, have edited question per tcb's suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

> With the unit tests that I did the vertices in the graph return null.

The reason is the following lines:

```
listGraph.addBidirectionalEdge(mySquareGrid[i][j], (mySquareGrid[i][j+1]), 1);
listGraph.addBidirectionalEdge(mySquareGrid[i][j], (mySquareGrid[i+1][j]), 1);
listGraph.addBidirectionalEdge(mySquareGrid[i][j], (mySquareGrid[i+1][j+1]), 1);
```

You are in the middle of initialization of `mySquareGrid` and create edges with nodes from future. These nodes with `j+1` and `i+1` are nulls at this moment.

Try the simplest solution - after grid initialization do the same cycling through grid and create graph's edges.

Also, you can try to change it to the following:

```
listGraph.addBidirectionalEdge(mySquareGrid[i][j-1], (mySquareGrid[i][j]), 1);
listGraph.addBidirectionalEdge(mySquareGrid[i-1][j], (mySquareGrid[i][j]), 1);
listGraph.addBidirectionalEdge(mySquareGrid[i-1][j-1], (mySquareGrid[i][j]), 1);
```

Comment: Say the vertices are 4,4 (x and y, respectively): [i][j-1] 4,3, adjacent to 4,4 (north). [i-1][j] 3,4, adjacent to 4,4 (west).  [i-1][j-1] 3,3, adjacent to 4,4 (north-west). However, [i-1][j-1] to [i][j+1] is 3,3 to 4,5, which are not adjacent. Are edges allowed between non-adjacent nodes?

Comment: I added conditional statements to be able to identify corner objects and border objects and then determine which objects are adjacent by using conditional branch statements: 'for (int i=0; i<width; i++) { for (int j=0; j<height; j++) { myHashMap.get(i+", " j); if (i==0; j==0) { int myRandom = randomno.nextInt(3); { if (myRandom == 0) { // code for moving objects into adjacent squares. This seams like a real long cut though. You would think there would be a simpler way to do this or an API that already provides this functionality.

Comment: It really depends on the algorithm you choose. Try to take a look at `myObjectGrid`. Does it provides you information about adjacent nodes? If yes, then you can build search algorithm using this grid only, you don't need to build a graph.